# Yii2: messed up data for separate sessions for frontend and backend

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I am logged in on backend, but for some reason, the data is loaded from the `user` model not from `admin` model;

The `admins` have theyr own `db table` and the `users` have theyr own`db table`;

The connection did not switched the `db tables`;

By using the `admin id` it loads the `user data` with the same `id`;

I use this config on `frontend`:

```
    'components' => [
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'session_frontend',
        ],
        'user' => [
//            'stateKeyPrefix' => 'frontend_stateKeyPrefix',
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
```

and this config for `backend`:

```
    'components' => [
        'session' => [
            'name' => 'session_backend',
        ],
        'user' => [
//            'stateKeyPrefix' => 'backend_stateKeyPrefix',
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\Admin',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually assumed the `stateKeyPrefix` you added as a comment would indeed solve the problem, but that only works for 1.x it seems. 
For 2.x the solution is a bit different:

```
    'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'idParam' => 'frontend__id'
        ],
```

You can leave one on __id or change both, it's however you want.